# how to get key name when the value contains empty in an object using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

If the object contains `{ name: 'abc', surname: 'xyz', Age: '', Description : '' }`

Here is my code

```
const abc = Object.values(data).some(z => (z === '' || z === null));
console.log(abc)  //returns true
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Age,Description
```

The code should returns `Age` key which contains empty or '' string

Comment: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) return values. If you want the keys use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys).

Comment: @Lain of you want to work with both, then [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.values` returns a list of values. If you need to work with keys, use `Object.keys`

`.some` returns a boolean depending the function passed to it returns true for any of the array values. To find the array value, use `.find`(or `.filter` for multiple)

```js
let data = {
  name: 'abc',
  surname: 'xyz',
  Age: ''
}
const abc = Object.keys(data).find(k => (data[k] === '' || data[k] === null));
console.log(abc);
```

Comment: what in case of  { name: 'abc', surname: 'xyz', Age: '', Description : '' , score: '' }

Comment: it should return Age Description score

Comment: @anushaanu Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @anushaanu as I mentioned in the answer `or .filter for multiple`